# Re-render a bar graph using the same function, but different data in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I am using extjs for creating bar graph using a function, which on update still shows the previous bar graph as well as the new one.. I wanted to remove previous bar graph and show current graph. I have used renderTo on the same  tag.  How can I remove the previous bar graph or is there a better way to render a new one?

This my function getting repeat every time with change of year.

```
function drawchart () {
    genresC = new Ext.data.Store({
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            fields: ['years', 'caseno'],
            record: 'rows',
            root: 'rows'
        }),
        baseParams: {
            param1: year,
            param2: ward_name
        },
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: filetogo,
            method: 'GET'
        }),
        autoLoad: true
    });

    var baryear = new Ext.chart.ColumnChart({
        renderTo: "baryear",
        width: 250,
        height: 250,
        store: genresC,
        xField: 'years',
        yField: 'caseno'

    });
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `function drawchart (year, ward_name) {` or something like that?

Comment: Also, looks like `genresC` creates a global variable, which should be avoided. But that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

The graph should automatically update when you refresh the store.

Try this:

```
var drawchart = (function() {
    var genresC;
    return function (year, ward_name, filetogo) {
        if (genresC) {
            genresC.setBaseParam('param1', newyear);
            genresC.setBaseParam('param2', ward_name);
            genresC.reload();
        } else {
            genresC = new Ext.data.Store({/*...as above*/});
            new Ext.chart.ColumnChart({/*...as above*/});
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked in my case, but when removed/commented                  //return function (year, ward_name, filetogo) {    Other left un-commented                                                                                                                        //}